# RealmList addAll duplicating object with same primary key

Tags: android, realm, realm-list, realm-java

I have a problem in inserting objects inside a realmlist. It is duplicating my objects inside Realm, and they have the very same primary key.

```
class ParentObj extends RealmObject {
   RealmList<SomeObject> objects;
}

class SomeObject extends RealmObject {
   @PrimaryKey
   @Required
   String id;
   ...
}
```

when I get a list of `SomeObject` like:

```
List<SomeObject> objs = ...;
User.getObjects().addAll(objs);
```

my RealmList (`objects`) gets duplicated. I've made sure it is the same primary key.
Anyone has any idea of what is happenning?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RealmList works just like an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), so the same item can be there multiple times. If you want to update `SomeObject` you should just do that directly. The `objects` RealmList will reflect those changes.

It isn't clear exactly what you are trying to do, so from the given information it is hard to give more advice.

Comment: I get all objects at my webservice and update my local objects inserting it to my realmlist. I was expecting to not duplicate them when doing this.  Otherwise I would have to always search for my object and update each one of them everytime I make a webservice call.

Comment: You don't need to manipulate the `objects` array to update `SomeObject`, just search for and update, `SomeObject` directly. The changes will be reflected in the `objects` array.

Comment: if I understood correcly, I could do a Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate in the list `objs`, and the changes will be reflected in my `objects`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is the same mental model as working with a pure Java hierarchy where having a primary key means it is a singleton object.